# Strange Error encountered when running a model on Azure Auto ML

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, automl, azure-auto-ml

I have been working on a classifier for a few days on Azure Auto ML and when I tried disabling some variables that I do not need, I encountered the below error.
I have never encountered this type of error before. Even after creating a new dataset with just the variables I am interested in, the error persists. I need help to resolve this issue. Thank you

The only SQL code that you will on my Data sets on Auto ML is SELECT * FROM my_table and it works since I can see the data on Azure ML studio. Plus I only started to have this error yesterday and I do not know why.

Encountered error while fetching data.

```
Error Code: ScriptExecution.Database.Unexpected
Native Error: Dataflow visit error: ExecutionError(DatabaseError(Unknown("SQLError(Server(TokenError { code: 103010, state: 1, class: 16, message: \"Parse error at line: 1, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near 'stmt'.\", server: \"data-platform-sql-data-warehouse-server\", procedure: \"\", line: 1 }))", Some(SQLError(Server(TokenError { code: 103010, state: 1, class: 16, message: "Parse error at line: 1, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near 'stmt'.", server: "data-platform-sql-data-warehouse-server", procedure: "", line: 1 }))))))
    VisitError(ExecutionError(DatabaseError(Unknown("SQLError(Server(TokenError { code: 103010, state: 1, class: 16, message: \"Parse error at line: 1, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near 'stmt'.\", server: \"data-platform-sql-data-warehouse-server\", procedure: \"\", line: 1 }))", Some(SQLError(Server(TokenError { code: 103010, state: 1, class: 16, message: "Parse error at line: 1, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near 'stmt'.", server: "data-platform-sql-data-warehouse-server", procedure: "", line: 1 })))))))
=> Failed with execution error: An error occur when executing database query.
    ExecutionError(DatabaseError(Unknown("SQLError(Server(TokenError { code: 103010, state: 1, class: 16, message: \"Parse error at line: 1, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near 'stmt'.\", server: \"data-platform-sql-data-warehouse-server\", procedure: \"\", line: 1 }))", Some(SQLError(Server(TokenError { code: 103010, state: 1, class: 16, message: "Parse error at line: 1, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near 'stmt'.", server: "data-platform-sql-data-warehouse-server", procedure: "", line: 1 }))))))
Error Message: Database execution failed with "SQLError(Server(TokenError { code: 103010, state: 1, class: 16, message: \"Parse error at line: 1, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near 'stmt'.\", server: \"data-platform-sql-data-warehouse-server\", procedure: \"\", line: 1 }))". "Ok(SQLError(Server(TokenError { code: 103010, state: 1, class: 16, message: \"Parse error at line: 1, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near 'stmt'.\", server: \"data-platform-sql-data-warehouse-server\", procedure: \"\", line: 1 })))"| session_id=af8ac40c-2ffe-410f-8ecb-70e45405ef78
```

Thank you

I just swicthed off some of the variables that my model does not need. So I would just create a new version of that data set with less variables that I could use for a new version of the model, which is something I have been constantly doing for the last couple of weeks.

I created a new dataset containing just the variables I need but I get the same error. Now I seem to be getting the same error always, no matter what I do.